Instagram basic display API implementation problem not fetching media like_count, comments_count, view/reach count,owner field
i have develop a Laravel web-application where Instagram user have to authenticate with their Instagram credentials and we are fetching user basic data like: username, id,access_token and also we have to fetch user posted media's like_count, comment_count and view/reach count,owner.but when using Instagram API , we are fetching other fields of user media post but cant fetch owner,like_count, comment_count and view/reach count.
first to create user access token as per below steps.


https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?app_id={$appId}&redirect_uri={$redirectUri}&scope=user_profile,user_media&response_type=code"



$appId = config('constants.instagramClientId');
        $secret = config('constants.instagramClientSecret');
        $redirectUri = config('constants.instagramRedirectUrl');

        $client = new Client();

        // Get access token
        $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token', [
            'form_params' => [
                'app_id' => $appId,
                'app_secret' => $secret,
                'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
                'redirect_uri' => $redirectUri,
                'code' => $code,
            ]
        ]);



 //long-lived tokens   
        $client = new Client();                    
        $response = $client->request('GET', "https://graph.instagram.com/access_token?grant_type=ig_exchange_token&client_secret={$secret}&access_token={$accessToken}");

        $content = $response->getBody()->getContents();

        $content = json_decode($content);
        $accessToken = $content->access_token;//its a longlived user token 

 $contentAcc = $response->getBody()->getContents();
        $content = json_decode($contentAcc);

        $accessToken = $content->access_token;

using this $accessToken i am calling below api
https://graph.instagram.com/{ig-media-id}?fields=id,timestamp,like_count,comments_count,caption,owner{username,followers_count}&access_token={$accessToken }
and getting error response
 "error": {
        "message": "Application does not have permission for this action",
        "type": "IGApiException",
        "code": 10,
        "fbtrace_id": "Agb9BCJHvMY7K0syAK8qgcp"
    }




"Application does not have permission for this action" seems like a fairly self-explanatory error message.

my question is how to activate this permission? generated access token already have scope for user_profile,user_media.

@webdev Fixed the issue? I'm having the same.
